# How does one go about fixing a memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks

I've got this game server that whether i download the pre-compiled binary or compile the source code myself just leaks until i have to reboot or enter a BSOD. I'm not super keen on C++ just currently classes for my degree but i can look at the code and understand whats going on. I'm just not 'fluent'.

Specifically looking at the resource monitor the modified memory type just fills and fills constantly by about 3-5MB per 5 seconds

is there anything i can do about this?

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report with the developer.  If it isn't maintained, well you need to start looking for memory that is allocated and never deallocated.  Tools can help narrow down but depending on the issues involved may be difficult for a beginner to track down in someone elses software.

Answer (score 1):

There is tool which is helpful for finding memory leaks: http://valgrind.org/

Comment: valgrind is linux only if im not mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever ever heard about a tool called `valgrind` you can run your C++ code in valgrind to see exactly where the leakages are.

http://valgrind.org/

Comment: valgrind is linux only if im not mistaken?

Comment: Yes it is linux only...are you developing for Windows? If not, there is not point in using Windows for a developer :D

And please accept answers for each question you ask.